# Items are not added to the collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simpe controller with its view, I am trying to add an item to the collection through ng-click, but I just started playing with angular and I don't see why the following view adding items is not working, however I hardcoded some test items and they display just fine, I would appreciate your help

```
<html data-ng-app>
  <body>
    <div data-ng-controller="ItemsController">
      name :        <input type="text" data-ng-model="newItem.name"/> 
      description : <input type="text" data-ng-model="newItem.description"/> 
      maintainer  : <input type="text" data-ng-model="newItem.maintainer"/> 
      <button data-ng-click="addNew(newItem)">Add</button>
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}  {{item.description}}   {{item.maintainer}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ItemsController ($scope) {
         $scope.items = 
        [{name:'x',description:"sss",maintainer:'me'},
        {name:'y',description:"aaa",maintainer:'me'}];

              var addNew = function(newItem)
              {
                  $scope.items.push(newItem);
              };
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `addNew` function to the scope object. If you change the:

```
var addNew = function(newItem)
{
    $scope.items.push(newItem);
};
```

into

```
$scope.addNew = function(newItem)
{
    $scope.items.push(newItem);
};
```

you'll see that it should work just fine.

Comment: my fault i should have learned more javascript first! thanks a lot

Comment: on a side note i can also use clousers to expose it right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean without an example.